# How to make light only affect the roughness map?

Tags: lighting, normal-map

I have two lights in my animation. I want one light to be by general light that affects the whole object. But I have a roughness map that I am using to make specific parts of my object shiny. What I am trying to accomplish in the animation is to have my second light. Move right to left and only affect the roughness map. The reason for this, I do not want to add more light to the whole object. Just add light to the roughness map.

Comment: Hi :) can you give us some screenshots to help understand your problem better? Can you also upload your .blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here is the .blend - https://pasteall.org/blend/0bd90b09617e40dd9ef2a6b923d632a4
Here are the screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/TKuIIID

What I am trying to attempt. Is to have the Base color node not affected by the smaller closer area light. I want the light to only affect the roughness map when it is moving right to left.

Comment: I cant seem to see your textures in your `.blend`. Can you upload again with your textures packed into your file? File > External Data > Pack Resources. Regardless though I don't believe what you're trying to accomplish is possible using lighting because thats just not how lights and roughness work. Roughness can't just be changed on the fly. A rough object such as piece of clothing doesn't become shiny when you put light onto it. From what I understand you might have to try a different method to accomplish what you want to do